# Font folder in Windows Vista/7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, fonts

I just want to make sure, but is the font folder in Windows 7 and in Vista still "C:\WINDOWS\fonts" ?

If not, or if it's changeable, is there an available ENVAR that will point me there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge it's still at that location. Are you having problems installing fonts?

Comment: Alright thank you. No, I have an application which depends on fonts, and few free fonts have Unicode glyphs, so I want to use the wide array provided by Microsoft, but I can't redistribute Windows fonts. So, I decided to peek in to the fonts folder and use a font there, defaulting to a free font if it's not there. Thanks, and I'll accept when it lets me =p

Comment: Hehehe no problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `%windir%\Fonts` in case the local installation of Windows is not in `C:\Windows`.

Answer (score 1):

They are still there. Fonts can be installed outside of that directory by checking an option in control panel -> font settings, but even then you install the fonts by placing a shortcut in the fonts folder.

Answer (score 0):

They are still there. Fonts can be installed outside of that directory by checking an option in control panel -> font settings, but even then you install the fonts by placing a shortcut in the fonts folder.

Great advice but what are the steps for doing this.
This is like giving a little child a candy in a wrapper that they cant open. 
Unfortunately many forums are like this, only half of the solution is given or people post a problem but there is no FIX shown.

Becomes a total waste of time, I avoid most forums and answer sites for this reason.
Frustrating to say the least.

Try This(worked for me)
Start:Run: copy "%windir%\Fonts" from above and paste it into 
 the open box and click ok.
Sends you to Add Fonts
Under folders (c:\windows\fonts)
Click on Fonts Folder. list of fonts box will now populate.
Find the font you want and click on install