# Does Windows 10 installer migrate your installed fonts from your previous version of windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, fonts, windows-10-upgrade

Do I have to worry about losing my installed fonts when upgrading to a newer version of windows? In my case windows 10 from windows 8.1

Some fonts I have purchased and I don't want to lose them.

Comment: So backup those fonts and reinstall them if you end up needing to.  The official word is that everything that is capitable with Windows 10 will be migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does...

Windows keeps all your data in a Windows.old folder after an upgrade. So even if you do loose your fonts they'll be saved

The website you downloaded your fonts from should allow redownloads as well anyways

**See here as well**

[Where are the physical font files stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/407804/where-are-the-physical-font-files-stored)

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you summarized where the author should look in your own answer.