# Where are user specific font files stored?

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, file-location

This question helps where global fonts are stored: [Where are the physical font files stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/407804/where-are-the-physical-font-files-stored)

But I'd like to know where user-specific fonts are stored.  For example, when I right click on a font, I have the option to `Install` or `Install for all users`, so I presume the generic `Install` will install it to an %appdata% folder or similar?  I just can't find where that folder is.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `Install`, fonts will go into `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\` rather than `c:\%windir%\fonts`.

If you want to see where a font is installed to, navigate to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Fonts`, find a font, right-click it and go to Properties. I just installed this font using `Install`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I've just reinstalled windows due to broken system, I've gone to this location in my Windows.old folder, but can't see any folder called "Fonts" in the `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\` directory, although I had hundreds of custom fonts installed.  Is this the actual file location do you think or is it linked to another location?

Comment: If you think they might be elsewhere, how about using `dir` in the command prompt to search the drive for `.ttf` files?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't pick anything up I'm afraid. I've even searched for specific font names that I know I had and am missing.