# What is the bug that makes fonts not work after a restart when not installed for all users? Is it fixable?

Tags: installation, fonts, windows-11, non-admin

When installed for a single user, fonts disappear after a logoff. They are still in the registry and in the folder, but they aren't registered. Reinstalling them makes them work again. Why is that? Is there a way to avoid this?

I have tried finding differences in the registry and the folder but couldn't find any.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1597642/where-are-user-specific-font-files-stored

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1658749/1482432

Comment: @Gantendo I've changed the question to what my intentions were, because my original question doesn't seem to have really been able to help.

Comment: Please read https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Oh, yes - I tried finding out a way to install fonts from the command line for the last few days, so I was kind of locked on that.