# Where is font nyala.ttf stored on Winsows 10

Tags: windows, fonts

I thought I understood where fonts are stored on Windows (Windows 10 in this case):

```
C:\Windows\Fonts
```

I'm looking for the *Nyala* font specifically, which I can select in MS Office, e.g. Word. I was looking into the above folder using Windows Explorer, Total Commander (TC), and System Control Panel -> Fonts. Neither show a file called `nyala.ttf`. I have also searched the all of `C:\Windows` for a file called `nyala.ttf` but TC did not show any.

According to Microsoft's [Windows 10 font list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list) *Nyala* is listed as *Ethiopic Supplemental Font". This and the fact that I can select the font in MS-Office documents seem to indicate it must be somewhere. What am I missing?

Comment: Note that MS lists it as a "font-on-demand", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list . It can also be an embedded font within a document. If you wish, it can be downloaded from a number of sources,

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks. I guess it has been installed with MS Office 2019, since I can't select the font on another PC with MS Office 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the sale of fonts via the Microsoft Store, there’s now a complication in the familiar way fonts are managed in Windows 10 and how Office for Windows handles new fonts.

For as long as anyone can remember, all Windows fonts where in a single folder: `C:\Windows\Fonts`.
But not anymore …

Fonts installed from the Microsoft Store are put into Windows in an entirely new method.
These fonts are placed in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\` a hidden folder. If you have access rights, each font is in it’s own folder.
([screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/3RMsZ7Th/screenshot.jpg))

The familiar "Control Panel" has been the place to manage fonts. It’s still in Windows 10 but does NOT show any fonts from the Microsoft Store.
That’s because the ‘old’ Control Panel system only looks in the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder.

Comment: Thanks, found it! Unfortunately, the naming and format doesn't make it easy to find a specific font's TTF file.

Comment: Thanks! +1. It is particularly obnoxious that one must take ownership of the folder to even view its contents. Thankfully, one can still download free TTF and other fonts, such as Googles (https://fonts.google.com/featured), and install manually, which copies into the usual C:\Windows\Fonts folder. See this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/407804/where-are-the-physical-font-files-stored/407811

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the links. When I need a particular font, downloading and installing it in the traditional way is my favorite solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Manually Installing a Font on Windows 10

In addition to what has been said in the accepted answer, I found that by manually installing a font (TTF file) on *Windows 10* (can't tell for other versions of Windows), the TTF file is placed in folder

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts
```

The font is listed, though, when looking into folder

```
C:\Windows\Fonts
```

or when looking at fonts via `Control Panel` -> `Fonts`

A font installed this way is available only to the user who installed it.