# How do I minimize and restrict the number of typefaces in MS Word, without deleting them?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I can't create another folder in [`C:\WINDOWS\fonts`](https://superuser.com/q/265101/269574) to which to move the unused typefaces; see screenshot beneath.

[image]

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to be supported but you could always just move them out of the fonts folder to some other folder. Effectively they would be unavailable system wide which is akin to deleting them.

Comment: @Seth Can you please elaborate? The 2 answers beneath disadvise (re)moving or hiding the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are provided by the operating system and only used by Word.
It is highly inadvisable to remove the fonts from the operating system,
because this can cause problems for other applications or for reading Word documents
received from others.

What you could do is modify your template for the file `normal.dotx` or
`normal.dotm` and in the DESIGN tab create and save a theme using the fonts
you want to use.
Save the theme and use it for new documents, or apply to existing ones,
and you'll see that the fonts you chose (one for titles and one for content)
are always available at the top of the font list under "Theme Fonts".

See also the Microsoft article
[Change a theme and make it the default in Word or Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-word-or-excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904#__toc341889146).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can "Hide" the fonts you do not need.

Going into `C:\Windows\Fonts`, as you probably see some fonts appear as "Hidden" files. If you select the fonts you do not need a `Hide` button appears in the toolbar.

[image: Hide button]

But there is a downfall to all this:

> According to Microsoft documentation, the Hide fonts function will remove a typeface from application font menus. The font will still be available for drawing text, it is hidden from the menus. This will work for many, but not all, applications.
>
> Applications that use the Choose Font dialog or the new Scenic Ribbon controls will properly hide fonts. Applications that provide their own font toolbars or menus won't hide fonts unless they are upgraded.
>
> Source: [Why the Hide Fonts feature does not work in Windows 7](http://www.loseyourmind.com/Why-hide-fonts-does-not-work-with-windows-7.aspx)
>
> Source 2: [How to preview, install, remove and hide fonts in Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-install-remove-and-hide-fonts-windows-7)

So even if you move fonts, or hide them, if MS Word is using its own font selection user interface, it will not take the settings into account.

---

Disclaimer: **I do not have MS Word**, so this is not a tested configuration. The hidden settings are not supported in **Libre Office**